# Joomla 1.0 - Locating images within a template

Tags: templates, images, joomla1.0

I am trying to locate the images folder within the template in Joomla 1.0.

I can press Edit HTML and Edit CSS to edit the codes for the site, but I cannot find any ways to access the files in the template.

Did I miss anything? (I am too scared to upgrade to Joomla 3 when people say it's hard to backup and upgrade from Joomla 1.0.)

[image: Screenshot of my Joomla Template Manager]

Comment: You should really not use Joomla 1.0

Comment: **UPGRADE** Use FTP or SSH to access files.

Comment: Did you look in the template folder or the images folder? Also upgrade, it will be worth it  in so many ways including easy access to the templates.

Comment: How on earth are you using Joomla 1.0 still? Itw as released 12 years ago! You're system has security vulnerabilities so do yourself a favor and migrate to the latest version of Joomla

Comment: Hi @Lodder, welcome to reality;( This is what happens if people with limited knowledge run webserver software;) Just `WannaCry`.

Comment: This website has not been worked on for many years and I just came in. I really want to upgrade, but no idea how to backup the website when I cannot find access to all the files. The site is also running cPanel

Answer (score 1):

To locate images in the template, right click an image in your browser, and choose Inspect (in chrome. Something similar in other browsers). This will show you the path to the image. The path on the server will generally reflect the path in the browser. If not, check for a .htaccess-file in your site root, to see if there are directives redirecting the images folder path.

Also: Don't try to upgrade your joomla 1.0 to joomla 3 (regardless of what others here are saying): You will end up using a lot of time making your old, outdated design work in joomla 3. Also you will have all sorts of issues with your data. Still: Consider that Joomla 1.0 is will give you all sorts of troubles, so if you are serious with the website, assess the best way to migrate to a modern platform. Joomla 3 is a good alternative, but also consider other systems, depending on your competence. The normal migration route for Joomla will not work well with such an old site, so you'll anyway have to find a way to move the data you want to keep (...and skip old outdated data you dont need anymore!)

Comment: Is there a major difference between 1.0 and 1.5? My upgrade from 1.5 to 2.5 needed change of  two lines of code in template and reinstallation of extensions, all other upgrades ran without any changes. This question should move to the Joomla community.

Comment: Yes, there are major differences between 1.0 and 1.5, but there is an upgrade path. I have done these upgrades in the past, and they where always quite a lot of work. I think, for an unexperienced joomla user, doing an upgrade will give a lot of headaches.

Comment: Btw. Simen: I'm at the IT-department at uib, working with uib.no. If the site is work related you can contact me about it after the holidays: Jonas F Henriksen.

Comment: Oh hey Jonas! I study at UiB actually  It's work related, but also for gaining more experience and my studies

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, images are stored in the following paths (even in v1.0):

**/images**

**/templates/your_template/images**

Your template folder structure could be different.
The CSS stuff and the old HTML should be also in the template folder.

**Upgrading to 3.x**

Don't do that. Install a fresh Joomla and rebuild the menu structure, copy the articles content, etc. Create a new J3 Template.

Could be a nightmare with a complex site. You need some knowledge of Joomla 3, PHP, HTML, CSS and manifest files. I recommend to get help from a freelancer or an agency who is familiar with Joomla 3. (Better than wasting your own time.)

https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template